# How can I write the likelihood of this system

Tags: maximum-likelihood-estimation, probability-distribution-function

I am very confused about how to write the likelihood of the following function. I have tried one and it doesn't have a maximum at the point where it should contain a maximum. The formulation of the measurement looks like this.

$$ Z_m(\omega) = F(\omega, \Theta) + \eta_m(\omega)  $$

Here there are many $\omega$ points where I have observations and $m$ represents many realizations of $Z$.

Here $F(\omega, \Theta)$ is an expected value expression known to me that depends on the parameters $\Theta$.

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z(\omega)] = F(\omega, \Theta)  $$

I want to write the log likelihood probability $\log(p(Z|\Theta))$.

I am showing a plot of $Z$ at two fixed "$\omega$"s ($\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$) for many "$m$"s and I am also drawing the F as a constant.

It looks like the attached picture. The thing I notice is that the signal variance is depends on $F$ itself for that specific $\omega$. So, I want to basically model this $\eta_m$ as an exponential noise at each $\omega$ having a variance of $F(\omega, \Theta)$.

$$ \log(p(Z|\Theta)) = -\sum_{\omega} \left[ \log((F(\omega, \Theta))^2) + \frac{ \sum_{m} (Z_m(\omega) - F(\omega, \Theta)) } {[F(\omega, \Theta)]^2} \right]  $$

If I use this likelihood, I don't see a maximum at the $\Theta$ I expect to see the maximum. Is there something wrong with it?
[image]
[image]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTMBp.png) [image]
[image]

Comment: Please _edit your question for clarity_.  What is $F(\omega, \Theta)$?  While you're at it, I assume that $\eta_m(\omega)$ is Gaussian noise, somehow, but could you say what it is, in the text?  In particular, in calling out $m$ and $\omega$ you may be emphasizing that you're sampling a random process, or you may be calling out that $\eta_m(\omega)$ has expected values that vary with $m$ and $\omega$ -- when you're editing, please clarify this.

Comment: I edited the question. The thing I am interested in is how to model the $\eta_m$ so that I can write the likelihood. My observation says that at each $\omega$, the variance of this fluctuation is the same as $F(\omega)$ (that is also the expected value of $Z$). Is it clear now?

Comment: OK, so you have say $N$ samples at points $\omega$ and $M$ realizations. If you do not get the right maximum, your model (i.e., the likelihood) may be incorrect. Am I understanding you right that you do not know the distribution of your noise and only have observations of it? Are you sure that even $Z_m(\omega) = F(\omega, \Theta) + \eta_m(\omega)$ and/or that your noise is exponential? I am not convinced based on your plots. Can you maybe show a histogram?

Comment: I have added the histograms at $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. The fluctuations of $Z$ is proportional to $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the histograms you provided, it is very possibly correct that the data is exponentially distributed. However, the model $Z_m(\omega) = F(\omega, \Theta) + \eta_m(\omega)$ does not make sense to me. Rather, as you mentioned $F(\omega, \Theta)$ encodes the scale of the distribution. I.e., maybe something simple like
\begin{equation}
Z_m(\omega) \sim \exp(\lambda(\omega,\Theta)) \text{ with } \lambda(\omega,\Theta) = \dfrac{1}{F(\omega,\Theta)}\,.
\end{equation}

Assuming independence over the realizations *as well as* the "samples" $\omega$, the likelihood is then
\begin{equation}
p(Z;\Theta) = \prod_{\omega} \prod_m \lambda(\omega,\Theta) \exp(-\lambda(\omega,\Theta) z_m(\omega)) \,,
\end{equation}
taking the logarithm and reformulating a bit
\begin{equation}
\log p(Z;\Theta) = \sum_\omega \left( M\log\lambda(\omega,\Theta) - \sum_m \lambda(\omega,\Theta) z_m(\omega) \right) \,,
\end{equation}

which then simply leads to the ML estimator
\begin{equation}
\hat{\Theta} = \mathrm{arg max}_{\Theta} \log p(Z;\Theta) \,.
\end{equation}

It appears you have to solve the optimization for $\hat{\Theta}$ numerically.

In any case, this is all nothing more than speculation as I do not know anything about the process generating the data. Ultimately, maximum likelihood estimation is only (asymptotically) unbiased if the inference model is correct.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I will test it. i am already using a similar one now (recently changed it). However, there is a small difference. I will check carefully.